# vim: run a shell (not make, not perl, not ...), parse output, jump to error locations

Tags: shell, vim, vi

In a different editor, I am very used to this workflow:

1. Use a generic key combination to run any arbitrary shell command (e.g., `make` or `perl -cw script.pl` or `rake cucumber` or `rubocop -D -R` or `./my_fancy_build_script.sh`)
2. The editor runs the command in a subprocess, the output is scrolled in an editor window. Error locations (`file:number`) are parsed using a large(ish) amount of static regexpes (i.e., it is not necessary to tell the editor up front that the output is from `gcc`, `perl` or whatever other tool).
3. During (and after) the compilation, the output stays until I close that buffer.
4. I can press another key combination to jump to the next (or previous) error location.
5. I can manually navigate in that buffer (as usual) and when I press Enter, I land on that error location.

So far so good.

`vim` has `quickfix`. It seems to basically do what I want. I did not find how to execute step 1 though. I do know to use `:make` to run make, or how to use the Perl plugin to run a Perl script, or `:grep` etc.; I did not find a generic command that runs any old shell command *without using a language specific plugin*. If I use the usual `!` command, the output is a) gone after a keypress and b) not available to `quickfix`.

Is there something like what I'm used in my other editor? How would I do it in `vi`?

EDIT: I tried `:set makeprg='$COMMAND'` and then `:make` but that works only when the `$COMMAND` does not contain whitespace.

I do not want to manually redirect the output of the command to some file, and open that with `vim -q file` as shown in the `quickfix` documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vi doesn't have a "quickfix" feature.

If by "Vi" you mean "Vim", yes, the quickfix window is an almost exact fit for points 2, 3, 4, 5.

> 2. The editor runs the command in a subprocess, the output is scrolled in an editor window. Error locations (file:number) are parsed using a large(ish) amount of static regexpes (i.e., it is not necessary to tell the editor up front that the output is from gcc, perl or whatever other tool).

For compiling or running syntax checkers you will want to use `:make` and set the `makeprg` option (and possibly `errorformat` too) on a per-filetype basis:

```
:set makeprg=foo\ --bar\ -baz
:make
```

`makeprg` and `errorformat` are usually set either by your filetype's ftplugin or via the `:compiler` command.

For grepping, you will want to use the `:grep` command and possibly set the `grepprg` and `grepformat` option if you want to use a grep alternative:

```
:grep foo **/*.c
```

Beyond grep, compilers and syntax checkers, you can populate the quickfix list (and window) with the `:cexpr` and `:cfile` commands which are the closest thing to a "generic" quickfix command I could think of:

```
:cexpr system("foo")
```

> 3. During (and after) the compilation, the output stays until I close that buffer.

Yes, that's how the quickfix window works.

> 4. I can press another key combination to jump to the next (or previous) error location.

```
:cn
:cp
:cc5
```

You can create custom mappings if you want.

> 5. I can manually navigate in that buffer (as usual) and when I press Enter, I land on that error location.

Yes, that's how you use the quickfix window.

The quickfix window is not opened automatically but you can use `:cnext`, `:cprevious`, `:cfirst`, `:clast` and other commands to jump to errors in the list:

```
:cn
:cn
:cp
```

To open the quickfix window, use the `:cwindow` command:

```
:cwindow
```

If you want the quickfix window to be opened automatically when there are listed errors/locations, add these lines to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup autoqf
    autocmd!

    " automatically open the location/quickfix window after :make, :grep,
    " :lvimgrep and friends if there are valid locations/errors
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l*    lwindow
augroup END
```

Comment: _the quickfix window is an exact fit for points 2, 3, 4, 5._ - Your optimism is heart-warming. :)

Comment: Do you want to check files with spaces in names? Bad news: `:let &errorformat='%f\, line %l\, col %c\, %m' | cexpr('test file.c, line 7, col 33, some message') | cwindow`. The same works for filenames without spaces: `:let &errorformat='%f\, line %l\, col %c\, %m' | cexpr('test_file.c, line 7, col 33, some message') | cwindow`. Actually, it even works with spaces, just not with comma separators: `:let &errorformat='%f: line %l: col %c: %m' | cexpr('test file.c: line 7: col 33: some message') | cwindow`. Fun part: this is _not_ a bug. I didn't even get to quoting filenames for `makeprg`. :)

Comment: Previous experience tells me I'm not too optimistic, here, but… you *may* lack creativity :-) `:let &isf = ' ,' . &isf | let &efm='%f\, line %l\, col %c\, %m' | cexpr('a file.c, line 7, col 33, some message') | cw | set isf&`.

Comment: Actually, you're being wasteful with the comma, but basically yes, this would work: `:set isf+=32 | ... | set isf&`. To make it work for good you'd need to set `isf` to cover all valid characters for filenames on the filesystem the files being checked are living on. Vim can't tell what that set should be, and that's why this is the intended (mis-)behaviour and not a bug. Now compare with what the OP describes: parsing errors with (named) regexps. I suspect innocent new users might not appreciate the difference, either. This is the kind of crap syntastic was meant to deal with, you know.

Comment: Point taken for the comma. Yeah, regex vs efm may be a bit of a stumbling block for new users, but nothing that can't be solved with 30 minutes of toying with `:h errorformat`. Or simply stealing the one in syntastic ;-).

Comment: AFAICT syntastic doesn't use `errorformat` for these corner cases.

Comment: It used to but it's now a lot smarter than it used to be, parsing JSON and XML and all. `:make` and `makeprg` may not cover every possible situation but they certainly cover *most*, including the ones in the question. Unfortunately for the OP, Vim is not at all about abstracting stuff and giving generic tools.